# Sequelize: Model.sync({ alter: true }) throwing Deadlock Found Exception for Unique, ENUM fields

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I've already read the Sequelize documentation & already have a look at some blogs. But I did not find any solutions regarding that problem.

When I am running `force: true`, then it is creating new data. On that scenario, I am loosing all my data. It seems to be destructive for my production server.

Now how I can alter the corresponding table without having the deadlock exception?

Comment: Side note: It's not safe to use `sync` on production environment. Try to use migrations instead of calling `sync`. As for a deadlock without code we can't say anything for certain